# radian installed but "name not defined" in VSCode on MacOS

Tags: python, r, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install RStudio in VSCode for my local computer (macOS Monterey 12.2.1) by following this post: [Setup Visual Studio Code to run R on VSCode 2021](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/01/setup-visual-studio-code-to-run-r-on-vscode-2021/). I've successfully installed `radian` through a VSCode terminal by running `pip3 install -U radian`, but when I run `radian` in the VSCode Python terminal, it returns `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'radian' is not defined`. I wonder if there is any suggestion to solve the problem or a different recommended post for me to follow?

This screenshot shows radian is successfully installed but not found:[image]

This screenshot shows the r execute path from the VSCode R terminal:
[image]

Comment: What happens when you type `radian` and hit Enter into a Powershell terminal in VSCode? Same thing? What do your r.term and r.path look like for R and radian in the `settings.json`?

Comment: I think Powershell terminal is the default for windows, and $shell is the default for Mac. When I type `radian` in VSCode terminal it shows `zsh: command not found: radian`. In `settings.json`, `r.path` and `r.term` both are blank. I attached screenshots in my edited post.

Comment: If those are blank then you haven't done Step #7 in the R-Bloggers article you linked to in  your question. You have to tell VSCode where R.exe (r.rpath) and radian.exe (r.term) are on your computer.

Comment: I doubt if lacking Step #7 is the reason because I'm currently stuck at #Step 5. In the tutorial, the instructor immediately tested whether `radian` could run in python before moving on the Step #6. For me, `radian` could not run in python after it was successfully installed. I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: I understand radian could not run in Python like he showed in the video. If you're confident you installed radian correctly, then it's probably a %PATH% problem. Radian requires Python, but it also requires R, and VSCode needs to know where they are. I'd recommend proceeding onto the next steps, first by identifying the paths where radian.exe and R.exe are installed. Look at the 13:54-mark of the video and see that he has a path for radian in the Rterm: Mac field, whereas you don't in your screenshot above. Can you find where those .exe files are installed on your computer and fill them in?

Comment: When I use `file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")` under r terminal, it gives me the output `"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R"`. I assume this is the r path, so I put this in the `rterm:mac` blank on the settings page. Then I reinstalled `radian` in the terminal, but again, it's not found after successful installation (see the new attached screenshot, please). Btw, I wonder if it's due to the path is not really saved in the blank on the setting page because there is no `save` button I could find, but when I get back to the setting page after close it the path is still there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MacOS, but I did notice that the path you have for your Rterm in the screenshot above is different than the one at the 13:54-mark of the video. Yours is `/Library/Framework/R.framework/Resoures/bin/R` whereas his is `/Library/Framework/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/radian`. Can you navigate around your computer and make sure you're actually instructing VSCode to look in the right spot for radian?

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem on VS Code 1.71.2, on macOS Monterey 12.5.1. `r.term` needed the location of `radian`, which in my case was `\Users\[username]\Library\Python\3.9\bin\radian` (after installing `radian` using the `pip3` method recommended here: https://github.com/randy3k/radian).